# Prove from the peano postulates that the set $\{m \in \mathbb {N }: n < m < S(m) \} $ is empty.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**I want to prove from the peano postulates that the set $\{m \in \mathbb {N }: n < m < S(m) \}  $ is empty.**

I have the following postulates

---

The system $\mathbb {N } $ of natural numbers is a set $\mathbb {N } $ with a distinguished element $0 $ and a function $S $ from $\mathbb {N } $ into $\mathbb {N } $ which satisfies.

(i) $S(n) \ne 0 $ for all members $n$ of $\mathbb {N } $

(ii) $S (n _1) \ne S(n _2)$ for all members $n _1 \ne n _2 $

(iii) any subset $\mathbb {N' } $ of $\mathbb {N } $ which contains $0 $ and which contains $S(n) $ for all $n $ in $\mathbb {N '} $ must be equal to $\mathbb {N } $

---

Furter the order realation $\ge $ is defined as $m \ge n $ if the equation $m= n +x $ has a solution $x \in \mathbb {N } $.

(We also have defined addition as composition of the function $S $.)

I dont know how to do this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you clarify What is S? & What defn have u taken for Peano's Postulate. I see the wiki but very much confused.

Comment: Think of $S $ as the function $S(n)=n+1 $, but in the formulation of the set of natural numbers we haven't yet defined addition so the formula doesn't make sense.

Comment: I also can say that addition later is defined as $m+n=S^n(m) $

Comment: & peano postulates??

Comment: That is the assumptions made in the definition of $\mathbb {N } $

Comment: Further in the definition is n varying? or fixed?

Comment: $n $ is varying.